# Where is FID xxx used?

Tags: files

Is there a way to see where a file is used, with FID? I see the entry in the file_managed-table (Drupal 7), but not where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

To show a usage list for a particular FID (file ID) you can visit the following url on your site:

```
/file/FID/usage
```

Just replace FID with the file id you want to check the usage for.

You can see an overview of all file usage at `/admin/content/file`. You can access this page from the admin toolbar at Content > Files.

Here is an example of what the file usage table looks like on that page:

[image]

This shows the name of the entity where the file is in use, the entity type and the usage count.

Answer (score 0):

It's in file_usage :-)

In my case, the file was in the file_managed, but not used anymore. Therefore, couldn't find it. A neat module is auditfiles